# How serve static files in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, webpack

I have several tasks related to show sitemap.xml, robot.txt, some pdf files.

Client-side the latest reactjs + webpack.

I tried two ways via reactjs and via Nginx on the server.

1. on the server I added these lines

   **location ~ ^/(sitemap.xml) {
   root /var/www/html/public;
   }**

[image]

I tried to add it before and after the main location config but it doesn't work

2. the second option. I tried to add a route to the main router in reactjs but it doesn't work too, I just get empty page.

Comment: Is your sitemap.xml and robots.txt in your root folder, that is /html/public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess` file at the site root. In your case /html/public

Add this in your `.htaccess` file, this should take care of the React internal routing. [Docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)

```
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Regarding your robots.txt, sitemap.xml and pdf files. Absolute path should work fine, else post more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had he same problem with react js , you can try this, :

```
server{
    listen 80;
    root /home/user/website/build; # the root document of my react website
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name website.com;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    location /robots.txt {
            alias /home/user/website/build/robots.txt;
    }
}
```

You can add links as i did in /robots.txt and link them to static files.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to install a package called [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)

```sh
npm i -g serve
```

And then serve them using the command (replace the `build/` with directory having static files)

```sh
serve -s build/
```